# Intellij Idea - remove framework support

Tags: intellij-idea

I know how to add framework support, but how do I remove it?
In the Add Framework Support... dialog the current frameworks are not displayed so I can't uncheck them or something...

Specifically, I want to remove Google App Engine support

I couldn't find it anywhere...

My version is 13.0.2

**EDIT**: clarification: I want to remove the framework support from a single project, not entirely from the IDE

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You go to Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) - Plugins and disable the corresponding plugin.

Or you can go to Project Structure (Ctrl + Alt + Shift + S) - Facets and remove the corresponding facet from project; from here you can also disable automatic framework detection.

Comment: i still want to use the plugin in other projects. if I re-enable it, the framework support won't return to this project?

Comment: Tried removing the Facets, but it's still an app engine project (appengine-web.xml and development server)

Comment: You want to remove framework support from IDE or to remove framework from your project?

Comment: Then that's a different question, unrelated with Intellij. For that you remove the dependency from the build tool and any references to it in the code as well as any configuration files; everything manually. I do thing Intellij can do this automatically since it would leave the code in an inconsistent state.

Comment: I think it is related to intellij, because the framework support was added through the add framework support feature of intellij

Comment: Your 1st solution will result in the Cloud Code plugin being completely removed from IntelliJ, disabling it for all projects (and probably breaking them), and doesn't answer the question of how to remove App Engine support from a project. I suggest you remove this and only leave the 2nd part (to alter the Project Structure)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old topic, but I find a simple solution.

This function "Add framework support" add a module to your **.idea** folder. Just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Old topic but still relevant problem. I just was facing the same problem. After searching in Intellij options I discovered a menu called "Project Structure". That is the place for the solution.
You need to remove that Framework support. Only two steps:

1. Alt + F1 , E

   - [[image: 1]]
2. Select the framework to delete and then clic on "-" (in red)

   - [[image: 2]]

And thats it. No more annoying warnings. This is better that deleting .idea folder because I have a lot configurations and don't want to restart configuring everything.
Hope it works for another people searching for this like me.